# place inset into the main graph in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to insert an inset into the main figure using pgfplots. Here is what I've got so far.[image]

I want the outcome to be something like the figure shown in the picture below. What would be the easiest way of doing that.[image]

Here is the code I have wrote so far

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}%fitting functions
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}


\newcommand{\myfont}{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont}% used with mathpazo 


\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large},
            tick label style={font=\Large}}

\pgfplotsset{error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both, x explicit,
    y dir=both, y explicit,
    }
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/error bars/error bar style={semithick,black}}
%\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/label shift={0pt}}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    name=plot1,
    enable tick line clipping=false, % makes all ticks same width
    axis line style=semithick,
    width=9cm,
    height=7cm,
    legend style={at={(0.95,0.35)},draw=none},
    legend cell align={right},
    x tick style={black,semithick},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={{$\lambda^2-\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$} [{\myfont -}]},
    xmin=0,xmax=70,
    xtick={0,10,...,70},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    %minor x tick num=1,
    xtick align=outside,
    %xminorgrids=true,
    y tick style={black,semithick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={{$\sigma_t$} [{\myfont MPa}]},
    ymin=0,ymax=30,
    ytick={0,10,...,30},
    ytick pos=left,
    %minor y tick num=1,
    ytick align=outside,
    %yminorgrids=true,
]
    \addplot [black,very thick] file {tensilePPmain.txt};

    \node at (axis cs: 56,12) {\Large{\myfont $0.4$\,MPa}};

    \draw [semithick] (30,8.9) -- (45,8.9);

    \draw [semithick] (45,8.9) -- (45,13.8);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enable tick line clipping=false, % makes all ticks same width
    axis line style=semithick,
    width=5.5cm,
    height=4.5cm,
    axis background style={fill=white},
    legend style={at={(0.95,0.35)},draw=none},
    legend cell align={right},
    x tick style={black,semithick},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={{$\epsilon_n$} [{\myfont -}]},
    xmin=0,xmax=2,
    xtick={0,1,...,2},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    xtick align=outside,
    y tick style={black,semithick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={{$\sigma_n$} [{\myfont MPa}]},
    ymin=0,ymax=2,
    ytick={0,1,...,2},
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
    %at=(plot1.axis cs:0,0),    
]
    \addplot [black,very thick] file {tensilePPinset.txt};

    \addplot[mark=x,mark options={scale=2,very thick}] coordinates {(0.52,0.74)};

    \node at (axis cs: 1,1.5) {\Large{\myfont $\sigma_{y0}=0.8$\,MPa}};

    \draw [semithick,dashed] (0,0.74) -- (0.52,0.74);

    \draw [semithick,dashed] (0.52,0) -- (0.52,0.74);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were absolutely on the right track. You (just) need to place both `axis` environments in the same `tikzpicture` environment.

(Please note that I heavily simplified your code so it more obvious what has to be done to achieve what you want.)

```
% used PGFPlots v1.16
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        name=plot1,
    ]
        \addplot {-x};
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
        at={(plot1.north east)},
        xshift=-5pt,
        yshift=-5pt,
        anchor=north east,
        tiny,
    ]
        \addplot {x};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: How can I specify the location of the inset precisely rather than using "north east"?

Comment: You can place the inset wherever you want using the `at` key absolute or relative to whatever is known up to there. If a relative positioning isn't precise enough you can further shift the inset using the `xshift` and `yshift` keys as I did. Sorry, your question is too brood.

Answer (score 2):

Place both `axis` environments in the same `tikzpicture` environment. You can't however use `plot1.axis cs:..` like you tried, `plot1` becomes a like a node with specific anchors. So you can for example use `at=(plot1.north west)` to place the second axis' anchor in the top left corner of the first axis.

However, it might be more convenient to define a helper coordinate in the first axis, with e.g. `\coordinate (otheraxispos) at (20,30);`, and then use `anchor=north west,at=(otheraxispos)` in the options of the second axis.

Because I don't have your datafile, I used some random numbers instead. I also reduced the font size and size of the inset axis.

To get a white fill behind the inset you could add `\fill[white] (otheraxispos) rectangle +(4.5cm,-3.5cm);` before the second `axis` environment, and set `anchor=outer north west` for the second `axis`. It's not particularly elegant, but it does work at least. Here `4.5cm` and `3.5cm` correspond to the width and height defined for the inset `axis`.

(As described in the manual section 4.10.1 *Common scaling options* those dimensions are just approximations, so you might want to/have to change them a little bit.)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}%fitting functions, loads pgfplots which loads tikz
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}


\newcommand{\myfont}{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont}% used with mathpazo 


\pgfplotsset{
   compat=1.15,
   label style={font=\Large},
   tick label style={font=\Large},
   error bars/.cd,
     x dir=both, x explicit,
     y dir=both, y explicit,
     error bar style={semithick,black}
}
%\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/label shift={0pt}}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    name=plot1,
    enable tick line clipping=false, % makes all ticks same width
    axis line style=semithick,
    width=9cm,
    height=7cm,
    legend style={at={(0.95,0.35)},draw=none},
    legend cell align={right},
    x tick style={black,semithick},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={{$\lambda^2-\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$} [{\myfont -}]},
    xmin=0,xmax=70,
    xtick={0,10,...,70},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    %minor x tick num=1,
    xtick align=outside,
    %xminorgrids=true,
    y tick style={black,semithick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={{$\sigma_t$} [{\myfont MPa}]},
    ymin=0,ymax=30,
    ytick={0,10,...,30},
    ytick pos=left,
    %minor y tick num=1,
    ytick align=outside,
    %yminorgrids=true,
]
    \pgfmathsetseed{42}
    \addplot [black,very thick,domain=0:70] {rnd+x*0.3};

    \node at (56,12) {\Large{\myfont $0.4$\,MPa}};

    \draw [semithick] (30,8.9) -- (45,8.9);

    \draw [semithick] (45,8.9) -- (45,13.8);


    \coordinate (otheraxispos) at (5,32);

\end{axis}

\fill[white] (otheraxispos) rectangle +(4.5cm,-3.5cm);

\begin{axis}[
    enable tick line clipping=false, % makes all ticks same width
    axis line style=semithick,
    footnotesize,
    width=4.5cm,
    height=3.5cm,
    legend style={at={(0.95,0.35)},draw=none},
    legend cell align={right},
    x tick style={black,semithick},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={{$\epsilon_n$} [{\myfont -}]},
    xmin=0,xmax=2,
    xtick={0,1,...,2},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    xtick align=outside,
    y tick style={black,semithick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={{$\sigma_n$} [{\myfont MPa}]},
    ymin=0,ymax=2,
    ytick={0,1,...,2},
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
    anchor=outer north west,
%    at=(plot1.north west),
    at=(otheraxispos)
]
    \pgfmathsetseed{42}
    \addplot [black,very thick,domain=0:70] {rnd+x*0.3};

    \addplot[mark=x,mark options={scale=2,very thick}] coordinates {(0.52,0.74)};

    \node at (axis cs: 1,1.5) {\myfont $\sigma_{y0}=0.8$\,MPa};

    \draw [semithick,dashed] (0,0.74) -- (0.52,0.74);

    \draw [semithick,dashed] (0.52,0) -- (0.52,0.74);

\end{axis}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: The trouble with doing it the way you suggested is that the inset overlaps with the main graph. Look for instance the tick #2 of the y axis. I want the inset to be at the front, on top of the main graph.

Comment: @Gagik Sorry, missed that. You could add `\fill[white] (otheraxispos) rectangle +(4.5cm,-3.5cm);` before the inset axis, where the lengths correspond to the width/height of the inset. Also you need to change the anchor to `outer north west`. Will edit.

Comment: @Gagik Note though that the inset *is* at the front, on top of, the main graph. But the nodes for the ticklabels etc. doesn't have any background fill.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I used the `\stackinset` macro from `stackengine` to do it.  I also scaled the inset down to 70% by way of a `\scalebox`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}%fitting functions
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}


\newcommand{\myfont}{\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont}% used with mathpazo 


\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large},
            tick label style={font=\Large}}

\pgfplotsset{error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both, x explicit,
    y dir=both, y explicit,
    }
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/error bars/error bar style={semithick,black}}
%\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/label shift={0pt}}

\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
\centering
\stackinset{c}{}{t}{-5pt}{%
\scalebox{.7}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    enable tick line clipping=false, % makes all ticks same width
    axis line style=semithick,
    width=5.5cm,
    height=4.5cm,
    axis background style={fill=white},
    legend style={at={(0.95,0.35)},draw=none},
    legend cell align={right},
    x tick style={black,semithick},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={{$\epsilon_n$} [{\myfont -}]},
    xmin=0,xmax=2,
    xtick={0,1,...,2},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    xtick align=outside,
    y tick style={black,semithick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={{$\sigma_n$} [{\myfont MPa}]},
    ymin=0,ymax=2,
    ytick={0,1,...,2},
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
    %at=(plot1.axis cs:0,0),    
]
    \addplot [black,very thick]  {rnd+x*0.3};
%
    \addplot[mark=x,mark options={scale=2,very thick}] coordinates {(0.52,0.74)};
%
    \node at (axis cs: 1,1.5) {\Large{\myfont $\sigma_{y0}=0.8$\,MPa}};
%
    \draw [semithick,dashed] (0,0.74) -- (0.52,0.74);
%
    \draw [semithick,dashed] (0.52,0) -- (0.52,0.74);
%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    name=plot1,
    enable tick line clipping=false, % makes all ticks same width
    axis line style=semithick,
    width=9cm,
    height=7cm,
    legend style={at={(0.95,0.35)},draw=none},
    legend cell align={right},
    x tick style={black,semithick},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={{$\lambda^2-\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$} [{\myfont -}]},
    xmin=0,xmax=70,
    xtick={0,10,...,70},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    %minor x tick num=1,
    xtick align=outside,
    %xminorgrids=true,
    y tick style={black,semithick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={{$\sigma_t$} [{\myfont MPa}]},
    ymin=0,ymax=30,
    ytick={0,10,...,30},
    ytick pos=left,
    %minor y tick num=1,
    ytick align=outside,
    %yminorgrids=true,
]
    \addplot [black,very thick,domain=0:70]  {rnd+x*0.3};
%
    \node at (axis cs: 56,12) {\Large{\myfont $0.4$\,MPa}};
%
    \draw [semithick] (30,8.9) -- (45,8.9);
%
    \draw [semithick] (45,8.9) -- (45,13.8);
%
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using \foreground and \background sets and just inserted a white rectangle to cover the line of the main graph. Here is the complete code and the outcome.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}%fitting functions
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,1000 sep={}}


\newcommand{\myfont}{\fontfamily{cmss}\fontseries{ul}\selectfont}% used with mathpazo


\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15} \pgfplotsset{label style={font=\Large},
            tick label style={font=\Large}}

\pgfplotsset{error bars/.cd,
    x dir=both, x explicit,
    y dir=both, y explicit,
    }
\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/error bars/error bar style={semithick,black}}
%\pgfplotsset{/pgfplots/label shift={0pt}}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}

\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\begin{axis}[
    name=plot1,
    enable tick line clipping=false, % makes all ticks same width
    axis line style=semithick,
    width=9cm,
    height=7cm,
    legend style={at={(0.95,0.35)},draw=none},
    legend cell align={right},
    x tick style={black,semithick},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={{$\lambda^2-\dfrac{1}{\lambda}$} [{\myfont -}]},
    xmin=0,xmax=70,
    xtick={0,10,...,70},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    xtick align=outside,
    y tick style={black,semithick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={{$\sigma_t$} [{\myfont MPa}]},
    ymin=0,ymax=30,
    ytick={0,10,...,30},
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
]
    \addplot [black,thick] file {tensilePPmain.txt};

    \node at (axis cs: 55,11.5) {\large{\myfont $0.4$\,MPa}};

    \draw [semithick] (30,8.9) -- (45,8.9);

    \draw [semithick] (45,8.9) -- (45,13.8);

\end{axis}
\end{pgfonlayer}
%\end{tikzpicture}



%\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
\begin{axis}[
    at={(100,310)},
    enable tick line clipping=false, % makes all ticks same width
    axis line style=semithick,
    width=5cm,
    height=4cm,
    axis background style={fill=white},
    legend style={at={(0.95,0.35)},draw=none},
    legend cell align={right},
    x tick style={black,semithick},
    x label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    xlabel={{$\epsilon_n$} [{\myfont -}]},
    xmin=0,xmax=2,
    xtick={0,1,...,2},
    xtick pos=bottom,
    xtick align=outside,
    y tick style={black,semithick},
    y label style=
        {at={(ticklabel cs:0.5)},anchor=near ticklabel},
    ylabel={{$\sigma_n$} [{\myfont MPa}]},
    ymin=0,ymax=2,
    ytick={0,1,...,2},
    ytick pos=left,
    ytick align=outside,
    %at=(plot1.axis cs:0,0),    
]
    \addplot [black,thick] file {tensilePPinset.txt};

    \addplot[mark=x,mark options={scale=2,thick}] coordinates {(0.52,0.74)};

    \node at (axis cs: 1,1.5) {\large{\myfont $\sigma_{y0}=0.8$\,MPa}};

    \draw [semithick,dashed] (0,0.74) -- (0.52,0.74);

    \draw [semithick,dashed] (0.53,0) -- (0.53,0.74);

\end{axis}
\end{pgfonlayer}

\draw [white,ultra thin,fill=white] (0.2,5.3) rectangle (5.5,5.5);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

[image]

It does solve the problem, however I wouldn't mind to see more clever solutions.